# In F#, is it possible to check if two values have the same constructor?

Tags: function, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Assuming I have a big discriminated union type:

```
type Thing =
    | One of int
    | Two of string
    | Three of bool option
      ...
```

And I have this function:

```
let comp a b = match a, b with
    | One _, One _ -> true
    | Two _, Two _ -> true
      ...
    | _, _ -> false
```

Is there a way to write the function in a neater, shorter way that doesn't require me to list every single constructor?

Comment: You could use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection): `let comp a b = a.GetType() = b.GetType()`

Comment: @Funk I didn't realise it would be quite so concise with reflection. Is there a downside to this?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: It takes advantage of how DU cases are compiled into nested classes in IL. Not a huge downside from practical point of view, but it's important to recognize how F# constructs are compiled into IL (which is not always straightforward), because that's the layer you work in when using reflection API.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: It will also most definitely be slower, but you can call yourself lucky if that's a concern in this particular case.

Comment: `GetType()` will only work if the case has arguments though; argument-less cases are not compiled into a nested subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, this is not possible. Even if you could get the constructors for your values, they are not comparable because they are functions. There's a bit of boilerplate involved but you could define tag values and a function to map to the tags:

```
let thingCase thing =
    match thing with
    | One _ -> 1
    | Two _ -> 2
    | Three _ -> 3

let comp a b = thingCase a = thingCase b
```

This is flexible enough to work on sequences too:

```
let compSeq things =
    things
    |> Seq.map thingCase
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.forall (fun (a, b) -> a = b)
```

Note: you could also do this with reflection but it's generally best to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure how good it is performance-wise, but it is possible to do this using `FSharp.Reflection`.

```
open FSharp.Reflection

type Thing =
    | One of int
    | Two of string
    | Three of bool option

let tagOfThing = FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionTagReader(typeof<Thing>)
// val tagOfThing : obj -> int

let isSameThingCase (a: Thing) (b: Thing) =
    tagOfThing a = tagOfThing b
```

Use:

```
> isSameThingCase (One 1) (One 2);;
val it : bool = true
> isSameThingCase (Two "test") (Three None);;
val it : bool = false
```